# Add help link to FAQ

Tags: feature-request, site-faq, help

For some reason there is not a link to [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in the FAQ. I think a link to it should be added to the [What if I need more help?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#what-about) section of the FAQ on every Stack Exchange site.

The said section currently looks like somewhat like this:

> #### What if I need more help?
>
> If you’re looking for excruciating detail, our [meta-discussion site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) hosts a section of constantly evolving [**frequently asked questions**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) that document everything about the site. Or, maybe you’d just like to learn a little more about us?

I think it should look more like this:

> #### What if I need more help?
>
> See our [**help center**](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for solutions to common problems. Your problem may be listed there along with possible solutions.
>
> If you’re looking for excruciating detail, our [meta-discussion site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) hosts a section of constantly evolving [**frequently asked questions**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) that document everything about the site. Or, maybe you’d just like to learn a little more about us?

My paragraph should probably be revised, but that is the basic idea.

This would make it easier to find, so fewer people who don't know where it is will ask questions on meta that will only be answered with links to [help](/help) and closed.

Comment: It's really cool to see that you've taken such an interest in the way new users are guided. Stuff like this is easily missed by people who have been using the system for a length of time. Thanks for another good suggestion.