# Add 'Stack Exchange Community FAQ' pages to 'help' search results

Tags: feature-request, search, review-audits, help-center

As sort of an 'inverse' to this request, "[Add help link to FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159948/add-help-link-to-faq)," I propose tying in the "[FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)" content into the 'help' search function on all SE network sites.  Even if just the question titles on the FAQ page were included, I think it would be beneficial. Indexing the contents of the linked questions for inclusion in a 'help' search would be even better.

For context, this request is prompted by my first encounter with review audits, on SU.  I [failed my first review audit](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9347/failed-audit-trying-to-report-apparent-bug-in-review-queue) because I thought it was a bug in the site, and freaked out a bit because (a) I hadn't even known that audits existed, and (b) I couldn't find any information on what the consequences were for failing audits.  The FAQ points to a good [overview of audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work), but searching SU help for 'audit' at present returns [zero hits](https://superuser.com/help/search?q=audit), and I hadn't remembered the existence of the SE FAQ.