# Help Center: add links to FAQs in detailed topics

Tags: feature-request

My initial search context:

I looked at the SO Help Center to find information about inserting an image into a post. Not just doing it - get to know the mechanics/ errors/ whatever.

As [the main help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159948/add-help-link-to-faq) does not have this in the short list, I went on to view more. Best match there was the sixth (btw: why not 2nd or 3rd?) entry about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I hit Strg+F for "image" - no results. K, "pic" - "what topics" - not my aim.

So I came on meta. Found a long and for me [useful list of FAQs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). Strg+f for "image" - that's what I was looking for.

I'm aware that the edit window has an icon for images and for straightforward putting in it seems sufficient. Maybe I'm to careful that I didn't want to play with a question to find it out - just did not get an "how it works" answer in the help center.

**My feedback question is:**

- Would it be useful to place the meta-urls to the fitting help topics inline to the text?

  - If that is "too messy" - would it be useful to post useful links to a specific FAQ (and all as a sum up) at the end of each topic for further reading?

As far as my research went:

- A [specific link from help to FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258231/please-add-a-link-to-the-protected-question-faq-post-to-the-privilege-page-in-he) with main answer:

  - FAQs can be edited by anyone and are not official enough
- There is a suggestion the other way round: [link from FAQ to help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159948/add-help-link-to-faq)
- Found this [general help center introduction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center) which seems to get updates

So looks like the strongest contra arguments are:

- Not official, can be edited by anyone
- If it would be included: too much text to read

My argument is only:

- I searched for technical understanding in the help center and found nothing, I had to know to look on meta.

To add some "where it already is as I suggest":

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta